# Headline is missing from content in community cloud

Tags: lightning-experience, experience-cloud, digital-experience

I'm creating a site for a client and they demand a Headline component on the Home page but when I try to use the "Headline" component from the "content" I found it's missing in my org.
do you guys have any solution on how can I fix this?

[image: Here is the screenshot for reference]

Comment: Can you confirm which tempate you  are using

Comment: "Build your own"